# How to write alphanumeric codes to a file in Python?

Tags: python, pickle

I am trying to create random digits and have them stored in a file and I did some googling and came across the `pickle` function. I used it exactly how the tutorial did and now I need to know how to store all of the codes that I create in there? Here is my code

```
import string
import pickle
from random import randint

data = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
[data.append(n) for n in range(0, 10)]
x = [str(data[randint(0, len(data)-1)]) for n in range(0, 21)]
y = ''.join(x)

print (y)

inUse = []
inUse.append(y)

pickle.dump(inUse, open("data.pkl", "wb"))

inUse = pickle.load(open("data.pkl", "rb"))
```

Comment: What are you expecting as the output?

Comment: When I build it, it creates a random 20 digit number. I am wanting to store every 20 digit number that I create into the file.

Comment: @LayneTrout Then you need to use append mode `open("filename", "a")`

Comment: I changed `"wb"` to `"a"` and now I get an error: `TypeError: must be str, not bytes`?

Comment: @LayneTrout What you're looking for is the random module. Pickle is used for serialization and before you can use must be unpickled.

Comment: Do you really want a pickle file or will just a text file do?

Comment: @JohnLaRooy , a text file will do just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way of generating `x` is overly convoluted

```
import string
import random
data = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
x = ''.join(random.choice(data) for n in range(20))
```

Now, you can simply `print` `x` to a file like this

```
with open("data.txt", "a")) as fout:
    print(x, file=fout)
```

If you wish to append `N` codes to the file

```
with open("data.txt", "a")) as fout:
    for i in range(N):
        x = ''.join(random.choice(data) for n in range(20))
        print(x, file=fout)
```

Comment: Thank you! That is just what I needed. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear or anything.

Comment: If I wanted to put the data.txt file into a folder called data, would I just say `("Data/data.txt")`?

Comment: @LayneTrout, sure as long as the folder exists and has the correct permissions

Answer (score 0):

In the below line -

```
y = ''.join(x)
```

Lets say `x` is a list of random characters like - `['a', 'x', 'c', 'j']

After the above line executes, you will get `y = 'axcj'`

You can use `pickle` , to serialize the list object itself, so you would not even need `y` or `inUse` lists.

The code would look like -

```
import string
import pickle
from random import randint

data = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
[data.append(n) for n in range(0, 10)]
x = [str(data[randint(0, len(data)-1)]) for n in range(0, 21)]

pickle.dump(x, open("data.pkl", "ab"))

x = pickle.load(open("data.pkl", "rb"))
```

Please note the `ab` file mode, it is for appending to file, instead of overwriting it.